# Unity intercepts drag and drop file uploads to webpages

Tags: unity, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

Just asking if someone out there has seen the same quirk:

If I want to drag a file to a *dropzone* in a website (say gmail's compose interface) Unity brings up the window picker bar (Launcher) and I can't drop the file in the webpage.
It's like nothing happens.

I haven't seen if it happens in Firefox too, just tried it with Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with chromium when i want to upload files with drag and drop.

I suggest you do this trick: start drag your file and select the Chrome window with Windows(Super)+Tab. Finally it will focus you the chrome window and hide the Unity Launcher, so you will be able to drop your file correctly.